# How to total average in data in table field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table called

tb_applicants
with fields 'id','aic','name','total'

My problem is how to total all the total of applicant with same aic field value and divide it with 7 and save the average score to a new table called: fapptotal with field 'id','aic','name','ftotal'?

can anyone help me with this im working with a scoreboard system in php...and im still learing..please

Comment: `SELECT SUM(total)/7 FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT aic)=1`

Comment: @Mihai how to save it to fapptotal table the result total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this question has entirely nothing to do with `php`, `javascript` or `jquery`, This should do it:

```
INSERT INTO fapptotal (id,aic,name,ftotal)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t.id
 ,t.aic
 ,t.name
 ,(SELECT SUM(t2.total) FROM tb_applicants t2 WHERE t2.aic = t.aic)/7 thissum
FROM tb_applicants t
GROUP BY t.id,t.aic,t.name
```

Comment: it save all applicant with field aic in fapptotal so many times how to restrict it to save only just once? because the applicant with aic is just only 1 person...i want to save it to fapptotal once.

Comment: Try it with the `Group By` line at the bottom I just added, and you can run it without the first line `Insert` to test it and see if it is the results you want to insert into your table.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood. Try it (cann`t check):

```
INSERT INTO `ftotal` (`id`,`aic`,`name`,`ftotal`)
SELECT id,aic,name, SUM(total)/7 AS ftotal
FROM `tb_applicants`
GROUP BY aic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL="SELECT id,aic,name,SUM(total/7) as Total FROM tb_applicants GROUP BY aic";
$res=mysql_query($SQL) or die('something wrong with query');


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $id=$row['id'];
    $aic=$row['aic'];        
    $name=$row['name'];
    $ftotal=$row['Total'];
    $SQL="INSERT INTO fapptotal VALUES('$id','$aic','$name','$ftotal')";
    mysql_query($SQL) or die('wrong with query 2');

}
```

Your question is now totally solved